# Interstitial Ads in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can somebody tall me, how make interstitial ads in app?

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/games#unity

They say

Basic interstitial request
Here is the minimal code needed to load an interstitial ad.

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
…
private void RequestInterstitial()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "INSERT_ANDROID_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
#else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif
// Initialize an InterstitialAd.
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
// Create an empty ad request.
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
// Load the interstitial with the request.
interstitial.LoadAd(request);}
```

and after

```
private void GameOver()
{
if (interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
interstitial.Show();
}}
```

But interstitial variable is private for function and I can't use it in code.
When i initialize it in top of class, unity throw error. Can someone write little tutorial, how show interstitial ads in app with new plugin?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is meant by "interstitial"? I have checked various dictionaries and I am still not sure. The fact that a bilingual dictionary provides me with a word in my native language that obviously has the same ethymology as "interstitial", but which I have never heard before, did not help me, either.

Comment: Are you joking?
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/interstitial

Comment: No, absolutely not. And given that this question has not received any other comments, answers, or votes (neither up, nor down) so for, after roughly an hour of being posted, it is at least possible that there is something about this question that causes other users in here to look at the question and its title without being able to make a helpful comment, nor a question about clarification, nor to point out any downvote-worthy flaw.

Comment: Okey, i will try to find answer in docs, one more time :). Thank you for reply.